# Find $a+b$ for $a, b$ such that $(x+1)^{n}(x^{2}+ax+b) \equiv 2^{n}(x-1) \mod (x-1)^{2}$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

Since
$2^{n} = \sum_{0}^{n}\binom{n}{k},$
we have from the given congruence the congruence
$$\sum_{0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(x^{k+2} + ax^{k+1} + bx^{k} - x +1) \equiv 0 \mod (x-1)^{2}.$$

The given answer is $a+b = -1,$ and I noticed that for $k=0$ we "have"
$$x^{2} + (a-1)x + b + 1 \equiv 0 \mod (x-1)^{2} ,$$
and by equating the coefficients we get $a=-1$ and $b=0$ so that $a+b = -1.$

However,there seems no ground for one to draw such a conclusion? Because the sum of polynomials divisible by something does not imply each individual polynomial is divisible by the thing. My question is if there is any hidden information that can be utilized to draw the above conclusion? Or simply the intended approach is misled?

A preferred solution is a solution by high-school methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider $P(x)=(x+1)^{n}(x^{2}+ax+b)-2^{n}(x-1)$. Then you question becomes: Find $a$ and $b$ such that $(x-1)^2$ divides $P$. But $(x-1)^2$ divides $P$ if and only if $P(1)=P'(1)=0$.

Now, $P(1)=2^n(1+a+b)$ and $P'(x)=n(x+1)^{n-1}(x^2+ax+b)+(x+1)^n(2x+a)-2^n$, so $P'(1)=n2^{n-1}(1+a+b)+2^n(1+a)$

so the problem translates to solve the system $$ \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}1+a+b & = & 0 \\ n2^{n-1}(1+a+b)+2^n(1+a) & = & 0 \\\end{array}\right. $$

Clearly, this means that $a=-1$ and $b=0$.

Note: I am assuming that $n\geq 1$ in my answer. Case $n=1$ is easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot to add an additional condition that a preferred approach is not to use calculus. But thank you anyway. Of course calculus leads to an elegant solution. :)

Comment: I used only the Taylor expansion for Polynomials. Defining derivatives of polynomials doesn't use calculus, and I hope that the proof of Taylor can be done by induction without any calculus..

Comment: I found that the congruence $\sum_{0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(x^{k+2} + ax^{k+1} + bx^{k} - x +1) \equiv 0 \mod (x-1)^{2}$ seems to lead to a solution; for taking $x := 1$ we get $\sum_{0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(1 + a + b) = 0$ which in turn implies that $a+b = -1$, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

$(x+1)^{n}(x^2+ax+b) \equiv 2^n(x-1) \mod (x-1)^2$

We must have $(x-1) \mid (x^2+ax+b)$. Hence $x^2 + ax + b = (x-1)(x+b)$

Then $(x+1)^{n}(x+b) \equiv 2^n \mod x-1$

Letting $x = 1$, we get $2^n(b+1) - 2^n = 0$

So $b = 0$ and $a = -1$